# false swearing on Bhagavadgita

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana, vishnu-purana, sin

False swearing on Bhagavadgita. I know its the at most sin. I lied my date of birth in the court. I am feeling worst guiltness for that.
is there no way of getting closer to lord Krishna?

Comment: Where is Lord Krishna? He is in your heart. Reach out to Him. He will accept you. Even the worst of thieves such as Valmiki have been converted to saints, by merely repeating 'Rama Rama Rama Rama Rama Rama'. There is no mantra more powerful than the name of your Guru or God. Keep remembering Lord Krishna and He will Himself show you the way. This site is unfortunately not the place for personal questions. But just wanted to give you some food for thought. All the best.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Personal advice questions are not allowed on this site, so I'm closing your questions. Now if you want to edit your question to remove all personal details and make it more general, then it may be more acceptable.

Comment: @Sai Not just a thief, he may have even killed a Brahmana, but I'm not sure about that; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7123/36