# Who are the Rashmi gods worshiped before a Yagna?

Tags: vedas, gods, practice, vedic-gods

In [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/ZWCY) from the Baudhayana Shrauta Sutras, a text associated with the Yajur Veda, a ritual is described where a person who wants to perform a Yagna (fire ritual) begs the priests to give him the place where he's planning to perform in turn.  And the priests in turn pray to the gods to grant the person that place:

> Now he begs the sacrificial place to the priests. To the Adhvaryu, “O Adhvaryu, do you give me the sacrificial place." (He says), "God Aditya is the divine Adhvaryu, may he grant you the sacrificial place." "Be it so," is the reply. To the Brahman, "O Brahman, do you give me the sacrificial place.” (He says) "God Chandrama is the divine Brahman; may he give you the sacrificial place.” “Be it so," is the reply. To the Hotr, "O Hotr, Do you give me the sacrificial place." (He says), "God Agni is the divine Hotr, may he give you the sacrificial place." "Be it so," is the reply. To the Udgat, "O Udgatr, do you give me the sacrificial place." (He says) "God Parjanya is the divine Udgatr; may he give you the sacrificial place." "Be it so," is the reply. To the Sadasya, "O Sadasya, do you give me the sacrificial place." "God Akasa is the divine Sadasya; may he give you the sacrificial place." "Be it so" is the reply. To the Hotrakas, "O Hotrakas, do you give me the sacrificial place.” “Goddesses waters are the divine Hotrasarhsins; may they give you the sacrificial place." "Be it so," is the reply. To the Camasadhvaryus, "O Camasadhvaryus, do you give me the sacrificial place." "**Gods Rasmis** are the divine Camasadhvaryus; may they give you the sacrificial place." "Be it so," is the reply.

I discuss some of these types of priests, like Hotri, Advaryu, etc., in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6807/36).  But I'm interested in the gods mentioned in this passage.  Most of them are recognizable: Surya the sun god, Chandra the moon god, Agni the fire god, Parjanya the rain god (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6578/36)), and the various goddesses of the rivers.  And even Akasha, who isn't familiar, can easily be inferred to be the god of space.

But my question is, who are the "Rashmi" gods, who are the Chamasadhvaryus of the gods? The Chamasadhvaryus are a group of 10 or 11 priests who bear the drinking vessels during a Yagna.

If it helps, the Sanskrit word rashmi means rope or string, for instance it denotes the reins of a horse.  And it can also mean ray of the Sun.